# Installing SDA4PP plugin for Kriging in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kriging

I am trying to do kriging in QGIS. I have loaded the SDA4PP plug in.
Almost all of the items in the SDA4PP dropdown menu are not highlighted and are unresponsive when clicked on - including the kriging option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SDA4PP appears to require an old version of R. R-2.11.0 worked for me for kriging. For Win:

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/2.11.0/

After installing R and SDA4PP, in QGIS go SDA4PP -> Components/R Packages and select the R packages that the plug-in needs.

No guarantees I'm afraid. Nowadays I do my kriging with gvSIG/Sextante.