# SDA4PP not found? How to do Kriging in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation, kriging

I need to make kriging analysis in QGIS (v1.7.4). I found out, that it should be a part of SDA4PP plugin, but I just couldn't find it in any repository (even third party). It looks, like it just disappeared from the web.
Is it possible that I did something wrong?

Comment: It's marked experimental. Allow experimental plugins in plugin installer options. Don't know if it works with latest versions of QGIS and all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works for making it available for install. But it was beyond my ability and time capacity to make all these dependencies working on Windows Vista.

Comment: At one time I did manage to get SDA4PP working (for kriging) with QGIS, but not in the current versions. The new Sextante plug-in has several useful-looking kriging modules but I can't get anywhere with this either, just at the minute. It looks as if it's going to be very good, hopefully before too long.

Comment: Sextante plugin is very new and far from stable. It cannot be recommended yet but will hopefully be a very powerful tool soon.

Comment: Hi, is it necessary to do the kriging in QGIS? I am using SAGA GIS (opensource, much more tools) for raster analyses and processing and then load my rasters in QGIS for map finishing.

Answer (score 1):

The most robust way to conduct kriging in QGIS is via the [SAGA processing tools](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/kriging/index.html). It comes with two kriging techniques: ordinary and universal.

[Ordinary Kriging in QGIS - video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEUjmGpEKqs).

The SDA4PP part of the question is best answered in: [How to install SDA4PP plugin for Kriging in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21917/how-to-install-sda4pp-plugin-for-kriging-in-qgis)