# How to install sda4pp plugin with missing repository in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, qgis-plugins, kriging

I see that the repository for the sda4pp plugin went down in 2011.  Does anyone know if there is another way to download the plug-in with the repository missing?

If this plug-in is no longer available, does anyone have recommendations for kriging?

Answer (score 3):

Patrick, here is a previous, similar question (for your reference):

> [How to install SDA4PP plugin for Kriging in QGIS? - GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21917/how-to-install-sda4pp-plugin-for-kriging-in-qgis)

SDA4PP 0.201 appears in the older [QGIS Contributed Repository](http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed) in the Plugin Installer for my QGIS (Mac 1.7.4-4). You might want to make sure that repository is being queried and that 'show experimental plugins' is checked.

I think your best bet now is to use the new [SEXTANTE plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/sextante/), which is a processing framework that can link processes together from different providers (very powerful). You can install it by adding the [QGIS New Official Repository's](http://plugins.qgis.org/) url [(http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml)](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml) to Plugin Installer.

SEXTANTE offers interfaces to algorithms in the [SAGA](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html) and [R](http://cran.r-project.org/) packages, including some predefined for kriging under SAGA.

[image]

You will need to have those packages installed to utilize them inside of SEXTANTE. The manual is in the plugin package's download. Section 7 covers configuring external applications. If you come up with a good script using R for kriging, you might consider submitting it to the plugin author. That section of the manual also covers creating R scripts.

Comment: Just found this helpful link to a txt doc describing how to setup up SEXTANTE and SAGA - http://sextante.googlecode.com/svn-history/r154/trunk/docs/3rdParty.txt