# Qgis - Running SDA4PP

Tags: qgis, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install SDA4PP plugin for Kriging in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21917/how-to-install-sda4pp-plugin-for-kriging-in-qgis)

I'm trying to use the SDA4PP plug-in for QGIS but it doesn't work. The software says to me that I need the rpy2 plugin for python but I have no idea how to install it. I read about the use of the "easy_install" software to install python module but I was not successful in using it.

Could you help please?

Paolo Tizzani

Answer (score 0):

Google and G.SE can be your friend

[How to install SDA4PP plugin for Kriging in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21917/how-to-install-sda4pp-plugin-for-kriging-in-qgis)

If you want to try this, you should download the advanced installer from OSGEO 
http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#12-OSGeo4W-Installer

then choose the advanced install, follow the prompts to the package installation options and find rpy2 library.

ciao

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I try to do it and it install the rpy2 libraries but it still doens't work.